# jQuery changing Button value not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change button value dynamically but still no success read so many answers but for me no luck

**JS**

```
 $("#d").attr("value","dayaw");
```

**HTML**

```
 <button id="d"></button>
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hwff2dk/)

Comment: Do you mean text of button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about **attr** function, but you can use **text** to achieve your requirement.

For Static value

```
$("#d").text("<your-text>")
```

You can also use like below for dynamic value

```
var lable = "new lable";    
$("#d").text(label)
```

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hwff2dk/1/)

Comment: +Soham exactly i was looking for second option provided by you

Answer (score 1):

if its the value you want - use val(), if its the text -use text(); and you can chain them together:

```
$("#d").val("dayaw");
```

```js
$('#d').val('dayaw').text('dayaw').click(function(){alert('my value is ' + $('#d').val())})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="d"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you want to change text of button, use `.text()` function

```js
$("#d").text("dayaw");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="d"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code..
   $("#d").text('button');

Answer (score 0):

> when you button tag you have consider your button name as html, so you have to push html with a name

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#d").html('dayaw');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="d"></button>
```